# Identify Short Story (Harlan Ellison, I think)

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, william-s-burroughs

I kept the details out of the subject line, because the subject matter is a bit, ahem, well you'll see...

I think the story is actually a story told within the story by a character- but it concerns a man whose anus begins talking. He does it as a party trick for a while, but then a film grows over his mouth and he can't talk, and then eventually his eyes glaze over and his mind is gone.

It's all obviously a metaphor for selling out...it sounds like HE to me, and I've read a lot of HE, so I think he's probably the author, but I can't recall the name of the story. I could be wrong on the authorship, though...

Comment: I normally enjoy trying to help find these stories, but I'm not googling "talking anus".

Comment: @phantom42: It's fun! Try it from work and see what happens... ;)

Comment: @phantom42 - I know, right?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you're referring to a story in Naked Lunch by William S. Burroughs.
You can read about it [here](http://www.goodreads.com/work/quotes/4055-the-naked-lunch)

Comment: for an added bonus, there is also a recording of Frank Zappa reading that part out there! http://dangerousminds.net/comments/frank_zappa_reads_the_talking_asshole_from_william_burroughs_naked_lunch_in